# Problem with NSDate in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults and I have the code `mondayalarm = [prefs stringForKey:@"mondayalarm"];` and mondayalarm (first reference, not the key) is an NSDate. It's giving me the warning:

> incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct NSDate *'

How can i make it accept this without the warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent the warning:

```
mondayalarm = (NSDate*)[prefs stringForKey:@"mondayalarm"];
```

To fix your problem:

```
mondayalarm = [prefs objectForKey:@"mondayalarm"];
```

Comment: 'You can accept this answer in 11 minutes.' But until then, thanks.